# Almacenar la nueva variable y guardar cuando se modificó

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

necesito crear una funcion que me guarde la fecha de cuando se actualizo la variable:
**$nuevoIngreso->anticipo = $request->anticipo;**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
$nuevoIngreso = \App\Models\Registro::find($id);
$nuevoIngreso->anticipo = $request->anticipo;
$nuevoIngreso->save();

return redirect('sistema')->with('mensaje', 'Ficha Actualizada.');
```

}

Creé un nuevo campo en mi base de datos para almancenarla para no ocupar update_at.
Pensé en usar Carbon :: now (), pero ¿cómo guardo el valor en una tabla?

Comment: Pues accedes a la propiedad nueva y le asignas el valor de now

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que quieres, solo tienes que llamar a tu modelo y hacer las operaciones como este ejemplo:

```
$data = $request->only('anticipo');
// También podrías usar $request->get('anticipo');

$nuevoIngreso = \App\Models\Registro::find($id);
$result = $nuevoIngreso->update($data);
return $result;
```

De esta manera solo vas a actualizar el campo anticipo y es siempre recomendable usar get() u only() para evitar inserciones de datos en la DB de manera intencionada y maliciosa.

Espero haberte guiado y ayudado un poco. Saludos